# Redshift - Window function of values over the past hour

Tags: sql, postgresql, amazon-redshift, window-functions

I have a table with columns similar to: `event_id`, `store_id`, `event_datetime`.

For each event, I am trying to figure out how many events happened at the same store in the previous hour. I know I can run a query like:

```
SELECT 
    event_id, 
    COUNT(event_id) OVER (PARTITION BY store_id ORDER BY event_datetime 
                          ROWS BETWEEN 5 preceding and current row)
FROM mtable;
```

in order to get the 5 preceding events at the store, but I need this number to be variable to the total number of events in the past hour. Is there any way to do this? Otherwise I have to join the table to itself like:

```
SELECT 
    event_id, 
    COUNT(prevevents.event_id) 
FROM mtable m 
INNER JOIN mtable prevevents 
    ON prevevents.event_datetime BETWEEN (m.event_datetime - interval '1 hour') AND
       m.event_datetime
```

This query takes forever as it is a cross join and results in a cartesian product between the tables. Any suggestions on how to achieve this? There are several million events in the table so any improvements would be very useful!

Comment: Does "past hour" mean previous 60 minutes or the previous calendar hour?

Comment: Mean previous 60 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

I am unsure whether Redshift yet supports the *range* window clause. It if does, this should be as simple as:

```
SELECT 
    event_id, 
    COUNT(event_id) OVER (
        PARTITION BY store_id 
        ORDER BY DATE_PART(epoch, date_column)
        RANGE BETWEEN 3600 PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING
    ) cnt
FROM mtable;
```

If this functionality is not available, then I cannot see another option that a join or a correlated subquery:

```
select 
    t.event_id,
    (
        select count(*) 
        from mytable t1 
        where 
            t1.store_id = t.store_id 
            and t1.event_datetime >= t.event_datetime - interval '1 hour'
            and t1.event_datetime < t.event_datetime
    ) cnt
from mytable t
```

The correlated subquery *might* perform better since it pre-aggregates the data. For both a join or a subquery, make sure that you have an index on `(store_id, event_datetime)`.

Comment: From what I've seen, it does not.

Comment: @kevin.w.johnson: I was afraid of that... In that case, I cannot really see an alternative other than a join or a correlated subquery. I added a correlated subquery solution to my answer (unsure if it will run faster than a join).

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, we might be able to solve this in two steps.  First, compute the count across each store, for each hour, using `TO_CHAR` to determine the date to the hour.  Then, subquery and take the lag of this count, to generate the count for the previous hour.

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *,
        TO_CHAR(event_datetime, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24') AS event_hour,
        COUNT(event_id) OVER (PARTITION BY store_id,
                  TO_CHAR(event_datetime, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24')) event_cnt
    FROM mtable
)

SELECT
   event_id,
   LAG(event_cnt) OVER (PARTITION BY store_id ORDER BY event_hour) prev_event_cnt
FROM cte;
```

Comment: This seems like it's close. If an event happens at the end of an hour (ie 59 minutes), this would skip all events that happened the same hour, wouldn't it? I can try partitioning by the minute and including the last 60 maybe.

Comment: @kevin Yes, but this is in fact the requirement you actually did list in your original question.

Comment: You're right. I meant the previous 60 minutes instead of the previous hour. I'll be able to work with this approach!

Comment: The only issue this doesn't address is that if there were zero events in a particular hour, it will look to the last hour there was an event to get the count instead of saying 0.